# Traffic: Inbound and Outbound

Tags: networking, port

How can I enlist all ports along with it's IP, which are communicating to my machine ?
Communication could be either TCP, UDP or raw.
And could be unidirectional or bidirectional.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: `netstat -tulpenw` or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On current Linux distributions, [`ss`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) is the recommended tool for this:

```
ss -tuw
```

This will show TCP (`-t`), UDP (`-u`) and raw (`-w`) sockets. Add `-a` to also see listening sockets (*i.e.* sockets waiting to receive an incoming connection request, or open for incoming traffic in the case of UDP). Add `-r` to attempt to resolve addresses and service numbers.

Comment: Voting for this answer over the other purely because `netstat` is eventually going to be deprecated and thus `ss` is the preferred tool to use these days.

Comment: How will I know if particular traffic is incoming or outgoing ?

Comment: By “particular traffic”, do you mean particular packets, or connections?

Comment: I suppose once a connection is established, packets can be sent both ways. But I too was trying to find a way to filter output of ss to show "incoming" traffic only.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS ? 
For Linux: `netstat -tun`

- `-t` to have TCP connections reported..
- `-u` for UDP.
- `-n` to avoid name resolution.

`man netstat` for more options.
For "raw" (i guess you speak about ICMP, or anything that is not TCP neither UDP), you may use a network capture tool like `wireshark` or `tcpdump`.